# How to assign anonymous functions to an array in Octave?

Tags: arrays, octave, variable-assignment, anonymous-function, assign

Is possible to store *anonymous functions* in an array?

I'm receiving two different errors for different approaches:

```
f(1) = @(x) cos(x)
f(2) = @(x) -sin(x)
f(3) = @(x) -cos(x)
f(4) = @(x) sin(x)

error: operator =: no conversion for assignment of 'function handle' to indexed 'scalar'
```

```
f = [@(x) cos(x), @(x) -sin(x), @(x) -cos(x), @(x) sin(x)]

error: octave_base_value::resize (): wrong type argument 'function handle'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them into a cell array:

```
f{1} = @(x) cos(x);
f{2} = @(x) -sin(x);
f{3} = @(x) -cos(x);
f{4} = @(x) sin(x);

>> f
f =
{
  [1,1] =

@(x) cos (x)

  [1,2] =

@(x) -sin (x)

  [1,3] =

@(x) -cos (x)

  [1,4] =

@(x) sin (x)

}
```

Access the individual anonymous functions like so:

```
>> f{3}
ans =

@(x) -cos (x)
```

You can even pass arguments to a specific function in the array:

```
>> f{2}(pi/2)
ans = -1
```